# How can I add to this schema array with mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here's the user schema and the part I want to update is ToDo under User.js (further down). I am attempting to add new data to an array within the db.

data.js

```
app.post("/data", loggedIn, async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body.content);
  let content = { content: req.body.content };
  User.update({ _id: req.user._id }, { $set: req.body }, function (err, user) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    if (!content) {
      req.flash("error", "One or more fields are empty");
      return res.redirect("/");
    }
    user.ToDo.push(content);
    res.redirect("/main");
  });
});
```

User.js

```
  new mongoose.Schema({
    email: String,
    passwordHash: String,
    ToDo: {
      type: [],
    },
    date: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now,
    },
  })
```

Originally I was trying the .push() attribute, but I get the error:

> ```
> user.ToDo.push(content);
>           ^
> ```
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Comment: That means that user.ToDo is undefined and you therefore cannot push it. There's probably a better way, but I usually end up using something like: `Array.isArray(user.ToDo) ? user.ToDo.push(content) : user.ToDo = [content]`

Comment: It definitely exists because I see my initial value in robo3t. Ill try this though thanks

Comment: I just saw in your schema that you have ToDo as an object. You can't `push` an object.

Comment: Did you mean `user.ToDo.type.push(content)`?

Comment: With that it creates the array but nothing is added

Comment: that was replying to the other let me tryuser.ToDo.type.push(content) now thanks!

Comment: I get Cannot read property 'type' of undefined

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224381/discussion-between-nthnchu-and-jonah-g).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your problem is the callback is not the user. When you use `update` the callback is something like this:

```js
{ n: 1, nModified: 1, ok: 1 }
```

This is why the error is thrown.

Also I recommend specify the array value, something like this:

```js
ToDo: {
  type: [String],
}
```

The second recommendation is to do all you can into `mongo` query. If you can use a query to push the object, do this instead of store the object into memory, `push` using JS function and save again the object into DB.

Of  course you can do that, but I think is worse.

Now, knowing this, if you only want to add a value into an array, try this query:

```js
var update = await model.updateOne({
  "email": "email"
},
{
  "$push": {
    "ToDo": "new value"
  }
})
```

Check the example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3gUabo1mpqT)

You are using `$set` to your object, so you are creating a new object with new values.

Check [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/H1mHRjq0oCQ) how `$set` works.

If fields no exists, will be added, otherwise are updated. If you only want to add an element into an array from a specified field, you should `$push` into the field.

Following your code, maybe you wanted to do something similar to this:

```js
model.findOne({ "email": "email" }, async function (err, user) {
  //Here, user is the object user
  user.ToDo.push("value")
  user.save()
})
```

As I said before, that works, but is better do in a query.